# Module that displays articles under specific section in joomla

Tags: joomla, module, joomla-module

Can anybody help me build a module that displays articles under specific section only ? ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can find nice modules listing for displays articles under specific section only !!

- http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/articles-listing/16598
- http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/articles-listing/4212
- http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/articles-listing/10017
- http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/articles-listing/7102
- http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/articles-listing/7787
- http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/articles-listing/12523
- http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/articles-listing/7619

Good luck.